Postgres locks and deadlock questions
I have a postgres table:
CREATE TABLE clicks (
  page_id UUID REFERENCES pages (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  status                TEXT        NOT NULL,
  click                 BIGINT      NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (page_id, status)
);

and two execution blocks:
code_block_1:
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE clicks IN SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO clicks (page_id, status, count)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3 )
            ON CONFLICT (page_id, status) DO UPDATE SET count = clicks.count + EXCLUDED.count;
-- that insert query can run more than once on different rows in the table. so imagine that there is a code that generates that INSERT INTO inside a for loop inside that one transaction 
COMMIT;

code_block_2:
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE clicks IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO clicks (page_id, status, count)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
ON CONFLICT (page_id, status) DO UPDATE SET
count = EXCLUDED.count;
-- that insert query can run more than once on different rows in the table. so imagine that there is a code that generates that INSERT INTO inside a for loop inside that one transaction.
COMMIT;
    

Rows that are being updated by code_block_1 might be updated in parallel by multiple threads.
But rows that are being updated by code_block_2 are guaranteed that they will not be updated in parallel by another thread.
Given that info, on which lock can I give up on (if any), if I don't want to get deadlocks?

If you added SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE it means the table is protected against concurrent data changes, and is self-exclusive so that only one session can hold it at a time.

Rather than imagine it, could you show us your looping insert code (or something like it)? It really affects the question.

@Schwern The line of the insert will simply apear more than once:
BEGIN;
LOCK...;
INSERT INTO clicks...;
INSERT INTO clicks...;
...
INSERT INTO clicks...;
COMMIT;

You don't need either lock. Both inserts are atomic.

ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE guarantees an atomic INSERT or UPDATE outcome; provided there is no independent error, one of those two outcomes is guaranteed, even under high concurrency. This is also known as UPSERT — “UPDATE or INSERT”.


I'm not sure what the docs mean by an "independent" error.  It is certainly possible for deadlocks to occur.  That would seem like a "dependent" error not an independent one.  Although if the operations never operate on overlapping rows, maybe the deadlock can't happen either.

Taking explicit table locks is unnecessary in 99% of all cases, and the heavy locks you are planning to take are not only self-excluding (different from what you think), but they also conflict with autovacuum, which will lead to table bloat and maybe worse problems.
If your transactions affect only a single row in clicks, they can never deadlock, so you should simply do away with the explicit table locks.

They impact more than one row: -- that insert query can run more than once on different rows in the table. so imagine that there is a code that generates that INSERT INTO inside a for loop inside that one transaction

Why would you want to do that? is that a bulk load? Anyway, that's not what your question says. Even if you insert many rows, you shouldn't lock the table. Just make sure that you keep a certain order with the rows you insert (say, ascending in the order of the primary key), and no deadlock can happen.
